# PHP code gets error on one page and works on another

Tags: php

I have narrowed my problem down to this bit of code:

```
<?php

$mysql_host = "mysqlXX.000webhost.com";
$mysql_user = "a4935911_******";
$mysql_password = "******";

$con = mysql_connect($mysql_host, $mysql_user, $mysql_password) or die(mysql_error());

$db = mysql_select_db('a4935911_******', $con) or die(mysql_error());

$getuname = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($con, "SELECT username FROM users WHERE id = 4"));
$username = $getuname ['username'];
echo "Username = " .$username;

?>
```

I have this on two pages.
The first works fine and outputs 'admin' as expected whereas the second gives me two errors:

Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, resource given in /home/a4935911/public_html/requestUser.php on line 11

Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in /home/a4935911/public_html/requestUser.php on line 11

How does this only cause a problem on one of the pages? Any help?

**UPDATE**

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("mysqlXX.000webhost.com","a4935911_XXX","XXXX","a4935911_XXX");
$id = $_SESSION['uid'];
$getuname = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($con, "SELECT username FROM users WHERE id =   $id"));
$username = $getuname ['username'];
echo "Username = " .$username;
?>
```

Error:

```
Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /home/a4935911/public_html/requestUser.php on line 4
```

PHP is relentless. What have I missed this time? I'm very new to PHP as you can see.

Comment: You have mixed mysql in mysqli functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to use the mysql_* functions with [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php). Those are two very different things. Have a look at the [mysqli_connect](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php) function.

The error that starts it all is:

> Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, resource
>   given

This means that the mysqli_query function was expecting a mysqli link as its first parameter. Instead, it received a resource because mysql_connect will return a MySQL link identifier resource variable. A mysqli example from the [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php):

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'my_db');

/*
 * This is the "official" OO way to do it,
 * BUT $connect_error was broken until PHP 5.2.9 and 5.3.0.
 */
if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    die('Connect Error (' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ') '
            . $mysqli->connect_error);
}

/*
 * Use this instead of $connect_error if you need to ensure
 * compatibility with PHP versions prior to 5.2.9 and 5.3.0.
 */
if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
    die('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '
            . mysqli_connect_error());
}

echo 'Success... ' . $mysqli->host_info . "\n";

$mysqli->close();
?>
```

Comment: Thank you! That's solved it. I hadn't noticed that I'd actually used the correct function in my previous code. What is the difference? Some of my code uses the mysql functions and others use the mysqli...I'm new to PHP and have just adapted tutorial code for this so I'm confused

Comment: mysql_* functions are deprecated. You should stick to using mysqli (i stands for improved) or you should use PDO. http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Comment: Oh and there a lot of differences. For instance, mysqli allows you to use prepared statements, which are really important.

Comment: Okay that's great but now I've added a variable to my code to get the session ID but am getting another error now:
<?php
if ($_POST['sendRequest'] == "parse") {
$con=mysqli_connect("mysqlXX.000webhost.com","a4935911_XXXX","XXXX","a4935911_XXXX");

$id = $_SESSION['uid']

$getuname = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($con, "SELECT username FROM users WHERE id = $id"));

$username = $getuname ['username'];

echo "Username = " .$username;

}
?>

Sorry for how jumbled it is...

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in /home/a4935911/public_html/requestUser.php on line 5

I'd assume that means the problem is the $id variable but I can't see why. Session ID = 4 btw

Comment: I think you missed an **;** after `$_SESSION['uid']`

Comment: Yes, that's true but that hasn't fixed it. Do you think we could take this into a chat just until this is fixed please?

Comment: The problem has re-arose now. I'll post my code and error in an update of my question.

Answer (score 0):

**Try This:**

```
$mysql_host = "mysqlXX.000webhost.com";
$mysql_user = "a4935911_******";
$mysql_password = "******";

$con = new mysqli($mysql_host, $mysql_user, $mysql_password,'database_name');
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_connect_error());

$getuname = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($con, "SELECT username FROM users WHERE id = 4"));
$username = $getuname ['username'];
echo "Username = " .$username;

?>
```

**UPDATE**

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("mysqlXX.000webhost.com","a4935911_XXX","XXXX","a4935911_XXX");
$id = $_SESSION['uid'];
$result=$con->query("SELECT username FROM users WHERE id =   $id");
$getuname = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$username = $getuname ['username'];
echo "Username = " .$username;
?>
```

Comment: That's solved it thanks. Could you just take a look at my last comment on @Wayne's answer?

Comment: I think you missed an **;** after `$_SESSION['uid']` if this was the problem then its ok else i will suggest you to ask a new question where it's better to see formatted code

Comment: Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /home/a4935911/public_html/requestUser.php on line 6

Sorry for this but PHP is seeming to hate me...